# Create image in the server

Tags: java, image, file, url, struts

How to create an image in the server?

Whether I can create using `File` object or I need any other objects, please suggest anyone.

Answer (score 1):

In a Servlet it is possible to:

- Create a `BufferedImage`.
- Draw on it.
- Serialize it to bytes in RAM, using ImageIO.
- Provide the bytes to the client with an appropriate content-type.

Comment: +1 For reference, [tag:jfreechart] can be used this way. See also [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/).

Comment: @trashgod +1 for the reference to 'headless'.  I knew there was *something* I was forgetting to mention, but I'd lose my head if it wasn't screwed on (pun intended). :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html) for creating image.  And save that created image into server by passing server path.